# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEvents' of undefined" when trying to delete calendar events from Google Sheets

Tags: events, google-sheets, calendar, google-classroom

I'm using a code that I've found for deleting bulk events from google calendar, based on values from google sheets (the code is in the google sheet script editor).
It's working when I'm using it on my personal calendar, but when I try to delte events from a google classroom calendar (which I'm its manager), I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEvents' of undefined". Do you have any idea why this is happening?

```
function delete_google_calendar()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startYear = spreadsheet.getRange("B67").getValue();
  var startMonth = spreadsheet.getRange("F67").getValue();
  var startDay = spreadsheet.getRange("H67").getValue();
    var endYear = spreadsheet.getRange("B68").getValue();
  var endMonth = spreadsheet.getRange("F68").getValue();
  var endDay = spreadsheet.getRange("H68").getValue();
  var fromDate = new Date(startYear,startMonth,startDay,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(endYear,endMonth,endDay,0,0,0);
var calendarId = "mandel-institute.org.il_classroom682af58e@group.calendar.google.com";
  // First number: Year
  //Second number: Month (January=0)
  //Third number: Day

var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarId)[0];
var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
  var ev = events[i];
  ev.deleteEvent();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Apps Script offers to methods for retrieving calendars: [getCalendarsByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename) and [getCalendarById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarbyidid)

Thereby, since you have a caledar id available, you need to use the method `getCalendarById(id)`:

`var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)`

Since the `id` identifies a calendar unambiguously only one calendar (instead of an array) will be returned, so skip the `[0]`.